# Correct placement of freewheel diode

Tags: inductor, h-bridge, flyback, tvs

I have two questions on placement of freewheel diode in a H-Bridge circuit:

1)  In reference to the general H-Bridge circuit below, wouldn't it be safer to place the freewheel diodes directly across the inductor? Wouldn't this solve the problem of high voltage spikes getting into the supply rail?

2)  If it is ok to place the diodes (TVS) directly across the inductor, what would the orientation look like? Would the connection in the schematic to the left (with L2 and D6 through D9) works?

D1 to D4, D7 & D9 are TVS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLfvpY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: New question means a new question. You should edit this back and put that in a new one. You've drawn some kind of switching regulator with no power source, so you might want to read up on "switching regulators" a bit before asking again though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Supplement to Daniel's answer -- look up the breakdown voltage from the datasheet of a TVS. There is a significant range there. It can be very hard to spec the TVS such that it never conducts even when the supply is at the upper tolerance range during on period, yet it always conducts (breakdown) before the body diodes do even when the supply is at the lower tolerance range during off period.
2. The reactive current of the inductor when the switches are off would be no more than the driven current when the switches are on. The same capacitance that keeps the supply from sagging when driven on should also keep the supply from rising when off in similar proportion.
3. Using a resistive element to clamp the full voltage means the power is dissipated and wasted. If the power stored reactively is (mostly) dumped back to the capacitance of the supply, it is recycled and not dissipated as heat.

If you want to investigate TVS clamping further, look into bidirectional devices.

---

Response to new diagram in question:

The new schematic you have shown does not make sense even if you add a supply to it at any spot.

Below is just a buck regulator. Sometimes you see it drawn this way especially for LED type application.

When the switch is off, the stored energy of the inductor is transferred to the load (and C1 which supplies the load). You don't particularly want the "flyback current to die down very quickly", this energy transfer is an integral part of the switching buck operation. If the current never dies down, that is continuous current mode.

If you replace D1 with an active switch, then it is a synchronous buck or half bridge. Just search on these names, lots of information are available.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAPV4k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A H-bridge with an inductive load and fly-back diodes in-built into the MOSFETs (or supplemented) relies on dumping the fly-back inductive energy into a capacitor across the supply and therefore the perceived spike becomes a relatively small ramp up in voltage.

Within one PWM cycle (for instance) that small voltage ramp is nulled out. What you see over several cycles is a small triangular ripple voltage superimposed on the power rails. What you get is energy recovery and an increase in efficiency due to storing and reusing that energy.

So, determine the leakage inductance of the load, estimate the peak current in the inductive load and calculate the power supply capacitance needed to limit the ripple to (maybe) 1Vp-p.

I'm all for using the H bridge as efficiently as possible.

Comment: what is "leakage inductance" ?

Comment: @Daniel in this context it's the inductance of the load that forms the spark if open circuited.

Comment: ah, we usually call that 'inductance of the load' or just the inductance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to do it that way, because the reverse threshold voltage for the Zener needs to be equal to or greater than the supply voltage to prevent reverse breakdown during normal operation.

So then if you have to push THAT much voltage across the diode for the freewheeling current, two things will happen:

1. the diode will heat up A LOT (significant current x significant voltage = POWER)
2. the diode might not even conduct

For the case of #2, if the reverse breakdown of the Zener is greater than the supply voltage plus the Vf of the body diode in the MOSFET, the current will just go through the body diode anyway.

The real function of these diodes in an H-bridge circuit is to keep that current out of the MOSFET body diodes, which reduces the power they have to dissipate and the operating temperature.

Many times with low-power H-bridges, the diodes are left out without an issue.

Also, there's no need to make D1-D4 Zeners. They can be regular silicon diodes since they only need to forward conduct and clamp Vdd and Ground.